# Pandas throws a parse error after being caught by try except while code in the except is running

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in large csv files into pandas (up to ~20 GB), and using the dtype parameter to control what types are loaded to manage memory use. Occasionally one of the files has a bad row, such as one of the floats having two points (eg 3.45.23). Apparently, when using pandas.read_csv like this, it does not care about `error_bad_lines=False`, and just throws something like :
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0.0.10118473'`
and `TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float32') according to the rule 'safe'`

My solution was to, on the rare cases where this problem happens, catch the exception (with a generic `try: except:`, no error types declared) and go through the csv and fix any bad lines (by checking against a regex) before re-trying the pandas load.

When I do this, the exception triggers the except clause, I print the error at the beginning of the except, and then it moves on to process the file. But then, from the middle of the except block, a the same pandas error from the try block crashes the execution (no pandas in the except block). Crash point shown with comment below.

How is it running in two places like this? Is there a fix?

```
        read_succesufully = 0
        attempted_fix = 0
        while(not read_succesufully):
            try:
                self.in_data = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=usecols, dtype=dtype,
                                           error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)
                read_succesufully = 1

            except:
                print('error parsing, attempting to fix bad csv ' + filename, sys.exc_info())
                pattern = r'(-?\d+\.?\d*(e-?\d+)?,)+-?\d+\.?\d*$'

                with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                    lines = file.readlines()

                os.rename(filename, filename + '.bak')
                print('read in file %s with %d lines, attempting to fix' % (filename, len(lines)))
                #crash occurs here, with pandas ValueError????
                wrote_lines = 0
                with open(filename, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(lines[0])
                    for line in lines[1:]:
                        if(re.match(pattern, line)):
                            file.write(line)
                            wrote_lines += 1
                print('wrote %d lines and renamed original file with ".bak". now attempting to re-read')
                attempted_fix = 1
```